# Are there any exception logging components in Windows Phone applications?

Tags: windows-phone-7, logging

Are there any exception logging components in Windows Phone applications? Do you have any suggestions about logging records in Windows Phone applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For logging to Visual Studio while running, you can use `Debug.Write`.

As far as logging exceptions to a file, [WP7Contrib](http://wp7contrib.codeplex.com/) has an exception logging library that is available as part of [`WP7Contrib.Core`](http://nuget.org/packages/WP7Contrib.Core) on NuGet. WP7Contrib.Core's only dependencies are the Rx libraries.

**Edit:** You can use the WP7Contrib logging library like this:

```
private ILogManager logManager = new LoggingService();

private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs  e)
{
    logManager.Enable();
}

private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs  e)
{
    logManager.Enable();
}

private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs  e)
{
    logManager.Disable();
}

private void Application_Closing(object sender, ClosingEventArgs  e)
{
    logManager.Disable();
}
```

**Edit 2:**

Having said that, I'd probably just use an extention method:

```
// App.xaml.cs
private ILogManager logManager = new LoggingService();

public App()
{
    logManager.Attach(PhoneApplicationService.Current);
}

// LogManagerExtensions.cs
public static class LogManagerExtensions
{
    public static void Attach(this ILogManager logManager, PhoneApplicationService appService)
    {
        appService.Launching += (s,e) => logManager.Enable();
        appService.Activated += (s,e) => logManager.Enable();
        appService.Deactivated += (s,e) => logManager.Disable();
        appService.Closing += (s,e) => logManager.Disable();
    }
}
```

Comment: well. thank for your reply Richard . about WP7Contrib i have been found there have a WP7Contrib.Logging Component. but i can't found any document to describe how to use it? did you have any idea?

Comment: in App.xaml.cs logManager.Attach Argument is not macth

Comment: LogManagerExtensions.Attach is an extention method (indicated by `this` on the first argument). You use it like an instance method, rather than a static method. It also means that LogManagerExtensions must be defined a separate class (you can't add the `Attach` method to App.xaml.cs)

Answer (score 1):

[NLog is quite good](http://nlog-project.org/)

[And a somewhat older 
Silverlight and WP7 Exception Handling and Logging building blockk](http://silverlightlogging.codeplex.com/)

Comment: hi erno!thank for your reply. just for nlog is there have any else log record Components can be use Windows phone Application?

Comment: @kaichen - The NLog website mentions WP7 support, so I assume that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

I saw Telerik are talking about releasing RadDiagnostics soon. I'm planning to get a look at it in the next app I release. Details from http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/posts/12-02-01/introducing-raddiagnostics-for-windows-phone.aspx

Answer (score 0):

well.you can try WP7Contrib OpenSource Project At CodePlex[http://wp7contrib.codeplex.com/] and get Exception Log Record in the Windows phone Application.

if you did't want to use opensource Project 。 you can define Component by yourself. Store　Exception record as file in Isolated Storage。